# Possible way to resolve conflict on click action button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, buttonclick

I am using bootstrap library on button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="$(this).button('loading')" name="submit" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

and [**this JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xk2om9hm/7/) would describe my problem.

However i want to perform both the event synchronously.
two event: 1. text area validation & 2. loading state of button

P.S. after button press, my page is getting reloaded, so no point to include button state 'reset'

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Don't write your javascript inline. Write it in a JS file. On click, do your textarea validation and your input validation; if both are correct, submit your form.

Comment: FYI, don't name form controls `submit`, it overwrites the native `form.submit` function

Comment: Not sure if this fixes it for you... but check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xk2om9hm/25/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got solution:

Either you can apply loading state on form submit event `<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="$(this).find('.btn-primary').button('loading')">`, like this [**jSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xk2om9hm/44/)

or you it can also be handled by this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xk2om9hm/42/)